# send and receive serialized classes from a base class

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, boost, polymorphism

My goal is to create a base class that has a method to :
1. serialize and send to server
2. read back from server serialized bytes
3. recreate itself from serialized bytes

This is to avoid having a second class that would serialize, send , read back and recreate the result for your class.

In affect building in the communication for every inheriting class I may need in the future.  Any inheriting classes do not need to create a send/receive method since the base class already has that method.  They would only need to have the `void serialize(Ar &, unsigned)` method in order for boost to do the serialization.

My question is in the save method below will the `archive << this;` save based on the pointer and call archive on the sub class and NOT the base class?

To put it another way: would i need to write a new `save()` and `load()` method on a class that inherits from aTodo.h?  This is what I want to avoid.

The base class I have created is called aTodo.h:

```
#ifndef ATODO_H
#define ATODO_H
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>

#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include "protocolBaseServer.h"
#include "memory.h"
class aTodo{
  public:
   virtual ~aTodo(){};
   virtual void Do()=0;

   //used for a client to send and then receive result back
   std::unique_ptr<aTodo>  WriteRead(std::string ip, int port){

    protocolBaseServer protoConnection(ip, port);
    std::string objToSendStr = this->save(); //save to a string
    protoConnection.DoWrite(objToSendStr);//send string off to server; server does some work
    protoConnection.DoRead();  //read back in the result from the server to a string in object protoConnection
    std::string returnedObjectStr= protoConnection.getTotalMessage(); //save the read bytes to a string
    std::unique_ptr<aTodo> objectReturned=this->load(returnedObjectStr);
    return objectReturned;
   }

   private:

   friend class boost::serialization::access;
   template  <class Ar>
   void serialize(Ar &, unsigned){};//every class that inherits from aTodo must have a serialize function

//save pointer to this to a string
   std::string save(){
         std::string out;
         {
            boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string>>os(out);
            boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(os);

            archive << this;
         }
         return out;
   }
//write aTodo pointer from string
   std::unique_ptr<aTodo> load(std::string const &s ){
         std::unique_ptr<aTodo> p;
         {
            boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> is(boost::iostreams::array_source{s.data(),s.size()});
            boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(is);
            archive >> p;

         }
         return std::move(p);

  }


};
#endif
```

Comment: Personally I feel like this shouldn't be in the base class. It violates the single responsibility principle. This code should be in some other class which has responsibility for saving and loading objects from the server. But that's not what you asked.

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell I kinda agree. I don't mind it being there, but it leads to cruftier code. Also, the real question could have been answered by simply trying :)

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell why would it be less crudy that way.  I though it would be easier for me to 1. create aTodoInherited. 2. call aTodoInherited.writeRead().  You are suggesting that i create some static method in another class that handles the sending and receiving and that will be less cluttered?

Comment: As I write this I see what you mean.  I need to google single responsibility principle...

Comment: I'm suggesting that you have some other class that manages the server connection and reading/writing to it. No reason for it to be static. This removes the code for this from this particular class, cleaning it up and making it easier to reason about, which makes finding bugs easier, plus if you have other classes you can reuse the code more easily. The only thing needed in this class is the serialise method. Look up the single responsibility principle it will improve your code design skills.

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell I just got back from an explanation on "single responsibility principle" via the www.  I agree I will be pulling out the transport tasks and putting them into another separate class.  Then that class could handle other data types not JUST aTodo.  I totally get it now.  Thank you.

Comment: @sehe yes I should have "just tried it".  Although I would have missed out on a bit of bonus info. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fine. As long as you serialize through pointers (you do)
and the [types are exported](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export), you're fine.

Of course there are the notable issues with the API design (`load` should probably be static; `getTotalMessage` should probably not be separate from `DoRead` etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much sehe.  you have answered so many of my boost questions.

Comment: what do you think about load() writting to "this" pointer rather than to another pointer?

Comment: @user249806 I think you forget that you can't. How will it construct the proper subtype dynamically?

Comment: You are correct.   I will change it to static.  Thank you for the suggestion and explanation.